# trouble with delete user input

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, local-storage

I'm trying to make an array that saves to local storage and the user can sort the items, add an item, delete an item, and clear the local storage. I'm having a lot of trouble getting the delete or splice user input to work can someone please provide me with some advice.

This is the code I have so far please forgive me if it's bad, definitely keen to know how it can be made better.

```
...
<script>
    //lets my program know the books1 variable is an array
    var books1 = []
    //lets my program know the result variable is a string
    var result = ""
    //checks to see if the localstorage key booksArray exists, if it doesn't books1 has 3 books added ans is stored locally with a key of booksArray
    if (localStorage.getItem("booksArray") == null) {
        books1 = ["book1", "book2", "book3", "m", "p"]
        localStorage.setItem("booksArray", JSON.stringify(books1))
        // var theArray = JSON.parse("booksArray")
    }

    else {
        loadBooks(); //loads the books to an array with variable name listBooks
    }

    function loadBooks() {
        var result = localStorage.getItem("booksArray")
        var listBooks = JSON.parse(result)
    }



    function sortBooks() {
        var sortedBooks1 = localStorage.getItem("booksArray")
        var sortedBooks2 = JSON.parse(sortedBooks1)
        // loadBooks may work but haven't got it to yet. try redoing the project on books Array 2.2
        sortedBooks2.sort()
        document.getElementById("display1").innerHTML = sortedBooks2
        localStorage.setItem("booksArray",JSON.stringify(sortedBooks2))
    }

    function addBook() {
        var test1 = localStorage.getItem("booksArray")
        var addedBook = document.getElementById("inputData").value
        var addedBook2 = JSON.parse(test1)
        addedBook2.push(addedBook)
        document.getElementById("display1").innerHTML = addedBook2
        localStorage.setItem("booksArray", JSON.stringify(addedBook2))


    }

    function delBook() {
        //if (document.getElementById("inputData").value.length > 0) {
        var local = localStorage.getItem("booksArray")
        var delItem = document.getElementById("inputData").value
        var array = JSON.parse(local)
        var x = array.indexof(delItem);

        //test2.splice(delItem,1)
        if (delItem != -1) {
            delete booksArray[delItem]
        }
        document.getElementById("display1").innerHTML = test2
        }


    //     my test function    
    /*     function displaybooks() {
        var test1 = localStorage.getItem("booksArray")
        var test2 = JSON.parse(test1)
        document.getElementById("display1").innerHTML = test2[2]

    }
    */

    function clearLocal() {
        localStorage.clear()
    }
</script>
...

<body>
<!--i need to make the page so onload it displays the books--->
<form>
    <input type="text" id="inputData" />
</form>
<input type="button" onclick="delBook()" value="delete your books" />
<input type="button" onclick="sortBooks()" value="test me" />
<input type="button" onclick="addBook()" value="add your book" />
<input type="button" onclick="clearLocal()" value="clear local storage" />

<p id="display1"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You Can Try This Code For CRUD Operation For JSON data

```js
$(function(){
    var operation = "A"; //"A"=Adding; "E"=Editing

    var selected_index = -1; //Index of the selected list item

    var tbClients = localStorage.getItem("tbClients");//Retrieve the stored data

    tbClients = JSON.parse(tbClients); //Converts string to object

    if(tbClients == null) //If there is no data, initialize an empty array
        tbClients = [];

    function Add(){
        var client = JSON.stringify({
            ID    : $("#txtID").val(),
            Name  : $("#txtName").val(),
            Phone : $("#txtPhone").val(),
            Email : $("#txtEmail").val()
        });
        tbClients.push(client);
        localStorage.setItem("tbClients", JSON.stringify(tbClients));
        alert("The data was saved.");
        return true;
    }

    function Edit(){
        tbClients[selected_index] = JSON.stringify({
                ID    : $("#txtID").val(),
                Name  : $("#txtName").val(),
                Phone : $("#txtPhone").val(),
                Email : $("#txtEmail").val()
            });//Alter the selected item on the table
        localStorage.setItem("tbClients", JSON.stringify(tbClients));
        alert("The data was edited.")
        operation = "A"; //Return to default value
        return true;
    }

    function Delete(){
        tbClients.splice(selected_index, 1);
        localStorage.setItem("tbClients", JSON.stringify(tbClients));
        alert("Client deleted.");
    }

    function List(){        
        $("#tblList").html("");
        $("#tblList").html(
            "<thead>"+
            "   <tr>"+
            "   <th></th>"+
            "   <th>ID</th>"+
            "   <th>Name</th>"+
            "   <th>Phone</th>"+
            "   <th>Email</th>"+
            "   </tr>"+
            "</thead>"+
            "<tbody>"+
            "</tbody>"
            );
        for(var i in tbClients){
            var cli = JSON.parse(tbClients[i]);
            $("#tblList tbody").append("<tr>"+
                                         "  <td><img src='edit.png' alt='Edit"+i+"' class='btnEdit'/><img src='delete.png' alt='Delete"+i+"' class='btnDelete'/></td>" + 
                                         "  <td>"+cli.ID+"</td>" + 
                                         "  <td>"+cli.Name+"</td>" + 
                                         "  <td>"+cli.Phone+"</td>" + 
                                         "  <td>"+cli.Email+"</td>" + 
                                         "</tr>");
        }
    }

    $("#frmCadastre").bind("submit",function(){     
        if(operation == "A")
            return Add();
        else
            return Edit();
    });

    List();

    $(".btnEdit").bind("click", function(){

        operation = "E";
        selected_index = parseInt($(this).attr("alt").replace("Edit", ""));

        var cli = JSON.parse(tbClients[selected_index]);
        $("#txtID").val(cli.ID);
        $("#txtName").val(cli.Name);
        $("#txtPhone").val(cli.Phone);
        $("#txtEmail").val(cli.Email);
        $("#txtID").attr("readonly","readonly");
        $("#txtName").focus();
    });

    $(".btnDelete").bind("click", function(){
        selected_index = parseInt($(this).attr("alt").replace("Delete", ""));
        Delete();
        List();
    });
});
```

```css
body{
    font-family:Tahoma;
}

ul{
    list-style:none;
}

ul label{
    width:100px;
    float:left;
}

#frmCadastre{
    border:solid 1px;
}

#tblList{
    width:100%;
    border:solid 1px;
    text-align:left;
    border-collapse:collapse; 
}

#tblList tbody tr{
    border:solid 1px;
    height:30px;
}

#tblList thead{
    background:beige;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="frmCadastre">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <label for="txtID">ID:</label>
                <input type="text" id="txtID"/>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="txtName">Name:</label>
                <input type="text" id="txtName"/>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="txtPhone">Phone:</label>
                <input type="text" id="txtPhone"/>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="txtEmail">Email:</label>
                <input type="text" id="txtEmail"/>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="submit" value="Save" id="btnSave"/>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </form>

    <table id="tblList">

    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this  clearLocal method and change(correct) in indexOf

```
   function delBook() {  
         var x = array.**indexOf**(delItem);
   }


function clearLocal() {
      localStorage.clear()
      document.getElementById("display1").innerHTML = "";       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The local storage API contains a method for removing a single item: removeItem( key). So to delete your delItem you want to do:

```
localStorage.removeItem(delItem);
```